# Is it possible to save plane positions in edit mode?

Tags: animation, uv, rigging, edit-mode, npr

I am creating a 2D character and have set up UV warps for parts of the face such as the eyes and mouth.

However, when using the UV warp to change the eyes from facing front to facing the right, the eyes image changes as expected, but the position stays the same.

I need to be able to change the position of the plane in edit mode and save it as a "key pose" or something like that, so that I am able to change the position of the plane automatically whenever needed.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Let me know if I need to elaborate more or show some pics of my situation for you to be able to help.

---

[image]

This is how the eyes and mouth appear after transforming them from their front view to their side views using the UV warp.

[image]

This is how I need the planes to be positioned after the UV warp takes place.

---

I need to be able to automatically switch between the plane positions shown for the eyes and mouth.

Would this work, for example?; creating a bone for the eyes, linking that bone to the bone for the head so it rotates along with the head as necessary, and then using the eyes bone to create poses in the pose library for moving the plane left and right as needed for the side and front views?

Comment: some pics would actualy be nice :)

Comment: @J.Doe I have updated with pics and a possible solution that I was thinking of but have yet to try, let me know if you think that would work or if you have a better and or easier solution.  Thanks!